# Does anyone know why the following VBA has bugs?

Tags: excel, vba

I am really new to VBA. That said, Visual Basic is throwing an error claiming the following has a bug:

```
Sub FilterPageValue()
Dim pvFld As PivotField
Dim strFilter As String
Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("StoreNumber")
strFilter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("OHPivot").Range("BB2").Value
pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter
End Sub
```

It points to pvFld.CurrentPage = strFilter having the error.

I copied most of this from a forum page, and changed a bit of the code.

Any help?

Comment: PivotField.CurrentPage is a property valid only for page fields.  Is that the case in your scenario? Edit your question and explain what you are trying to achieve, because I don't quite understand what you want to do here.

Comment: "an error" and "a bug" are not very useful descriptions of what happens when you run your code.